# Importing sql file into Mysql running xampp using commandline in Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I have installed xampp in my macosx and i want to import the wordnet sql file its not working. i tried this command

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p dict < wordnet20-from-prolog-all-3.mysql
```

The commandline works without any errors takes a while to finish.

I fireup phpmyadmin and check the dict database and nothing is there. What is the problem?

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, you log in as which user?

Comment: xampp phpmyadmin has no specific logins, it just works in localhost with user as root and blank password.

Comment: In your .sql file, is there a USE statement that would switch to another database?

Comment: yes i think :) will remove that and see if that works. Thanks for opening my eye :D

Comment: Any feedback about this USE statement removal?

Comment: @MarcDelisle Yes the problem was resolved. I removed the USE statement and it worked :)

Comment: please mark the answer below as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .sql file, look for a USE statement that would switch execution to another database. It might explain why you see nothing in the database used on the command line.